# Cross-domain Ajax call with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I've been trying for days to make this work:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://otherdomain.com/mail.json' ,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: jsonObject,
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Thank you for your inquiry. We will get back to you soon.");                     
                }
            });
```

The `mail.json` API works when I use the Chrome Postman app to test and the response header is this:

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Alternate-Protocol →80:quic,p=0.002
Cache-Control →private
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →22
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Mon, 15 Sep 2014 05:18:09 GMT
Server →Google Frontend
Vary →Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
```

What could be wrong in my Jquery code, as the server works fine.

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: I can't see any error in the console, actually the page re-loads when the form submit button is clicked where this ajax call is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `http://otherdomain.com/mail.json` is from another domain. According to the "Same Origin Policy", you should not be able to send the request (Unless you simply open your HTML file in the browser with deploying to a server, something like `file:///C:/Projects/HTML5/WebContent/request.html`, I guess).

To make cross-domain Ajax requests, you can try JSONP as @Vivin suggests. So your jQuery code could be like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonpcallback',
    }).done(function(data) { // deal with your data
    });
```

In your server-side, your need to return something like `jsonpcallback(YOUR_DATA_IN_JSON_STRING)`. For a more detailed tutorial, you can search online. Here is a Chinese tutorial written by me: [JSONP Tutorial](http://shaojiangcai.com/jsonp%E8%B7%A8%E5%9F%9F%E8%AE%BF%E9%97%AE%E5%8E%9F%E7%90%86%E5%8F%8A%E5%AE%9E%E7%8E%B0/)

Answer (score 1):

For cross domain ajax calls it is preferable to use JSONP. You can get more information here:
[JSONP stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Answer (score 1):

As you saied,the page reloads when the form submit button is clicked where this ajax call is in.If using asynchronous submission,you should prvent the default action of browser.For exanple,

```
$('submit').click(function(e){
    //prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url: ,
       success: function(res) {

       }
    })
})
```